# Change cursor while dragging

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, drag-and-drop

When I hover over my element, I'm changing the cursor to grab:

```
.location:hover {
    border: 2px dashed #FF6600;
    cursor: -webkit-grab;
    cursor: -moz-grab;
}
```

That works fine. When the user grabs, the element, I want to change it to grabbed:

```
.location:active {
    cursor: -webkit-grabbing;
    cursor: -moz-grabbing;
}
```

This is not working as I expected. When I click and hold on the element, nothing happens, it's only when I release it that it changes to `grabbing`. Then when I click and hold, it goes back to `grab`, and when I release back to `grabbing`. If I move the mouse after it has become `grabbing`, it goes back to `grab`. I need it to be `grab` when I hover, and `grabbing` when I click and hold. How?

Also, when I actually drag the element, the cursor returns to the default one. I would like it to stay as `grabbing` until I drop the element. Is that possible?

More code:

HTML:

```
<div class="patients-container" [class.dragOver]="dragOver" (dragover)="allowDrop($event)" (dragleave)="onDragLeave()" (drop)="onDrop($event)">
  <div class="patient-box level-2" *ngFor="let bed of patientService.bedsLevel2">
    <div class="header-container">
      <div class="button-container">
        <button mat-raised-button id="close" (click)="closeLevel2(bed)"><mat-icon>close</mat-icon></button>
      </div>
      <p class="location" draggable="true" (dragstart)="onDrag($event, bed)">{{bed.philipsName}} - {{bed.patientName}}</p>
    </div>
```

.ts:

```
onDrag(event: any, bed: BedDetails) {
    event.dataTransfer.setData("bed", JSON.stringify(bed));
    event.dataTransfer.setData("from", "2");
  }

  allowDrop(event: any) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }

onDrop(event: any) {
    let movedBed: BedDetails = JSON.parse(event.dataTransfer.getData("bed"));
    let from = parseInt(event.dataTransfer.getData("from"));

    if (this.patientService.bedsLevel2.filter(bed => bed.cetreaName == movedBed.cetreaName).length == 0) {
      this.setChartData(movedBed);
      this.patientService.removePatient(from, movedBed.philipsName);
      this.patientService.bedsLevel2.push(movedBed);
    }

    this.dragOver = false;

  }
```

Comment: It looks to be working for me, what browser are you using?

Comment: @Bassie I'm using chrome.

Comment: Ok may need to see more of your code if I'm undersatnding your issue. When I recreate your example using a simple square div, the grabbing cursor displays when I hold down the mouse button over it. Try recreating your issue with a simple example like that then repost (also which version of chrome?)

Comment: @Bassie I'm using version 61.0.3163.100. It's pretty weird, because it's working for me here: http://jsfiddle.net/nXv63/1019/ but it's not working for me in my angular application, where I think I have the exact same code. I'll gladly share more code, just not sure what.

Comment: All I can suggest is to recreate that code exactly in your application. I noticed in your jsfiddle example youa re using id instead of class. How many of these elements appear on the page?

Comment: @Bassie In my application I am using class. Well, the CSS i wrote in the post is what I have in my application, and it's the same as what I have in the jsfiddle. I don't think there's any other code that affects it, but maybe I'm wrong. I added some more code.

Comment: in your jsfiddle css code is different. Here you are using ':hover' class which is not required

Comment: @ShishirArora I have tried with and without hover and it's the same result. :(